# Is it possible to hide the home indicator on the iPhone X during tap/gaming?

Tags: swift, iphone-x

I'm writing a game where the user taps the screen. The home indicator bar appears and disappears constantly as the user taps.

Is it possible to change this behavior so that the home indicator stays hidden until some special gesture is used? I know it's possible for the user to set this up in accessibility, but I'm looking for a coded solution.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887510-prefershomeindicatorautohidden

Comment: Doesn't work @matt - that only hides it until you tap, then it briefly shows. With constant tapping, it's pretty much visible all the time.

Comment: I know that. The docs say "but returning `true` is no guarantee that the indicator will be hidden." That's my point.

Comment: Yes I know that too. My question is asking if there's a way to do it, not "please point me to a method that won't work".

Comment: Here's an idea: maybe the tap that reveals the home indicator is caught by a tap gesture recognizer. Maybe you can find it and do something with it.

Comment: Also, there's `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures`, though I doubt that it includes the tap gesture on the iPhone X

Comment: Did you ever work out how to keep the home indicator hidden when a tap gesture is recognised?

Comment: @EuanTraynor Unfortunately no, it doesn't seem to be possible, although I haven't checked the latest v15 sdk.